# Adding User to Role with Asp.Net Identity

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, vb.net, asp.net-identity

I am trying to add a user to a role in VB.net with ASP.NET identity. One idea I had in mind was trying to use the IUserRoleStore but I do not know how to use it properly. I also am not sure if I am on the right path, anyone have a clue if I am or not?

I keep getting 2 errors over and over as seen in my Screenshots, *that I have provided as links*. One error I get is *UserId not found* error aka [Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRCmb.png). Keep in mind in this instance the error is raised when checking IsInRole(). The one thing that catches my eye is when looking at the stack trace I see

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManagerExtensions.IsInRole(UserManager`2 manager, TKey userId, String role) +140
```

I believe this could be the key to solving this problem.

And if I am able to get past that error my reworking my code or just simply only trying to AddToRole instead of checking IsInRole I get a lengthy a network-related or instance-specific error that for brevity I'll sum it up as Error 26: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified. This can be seen under [Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRCmb.png).

If anyone is interested in helping me solve this, please let me know so I can post the code you need to help understand cause it is pretty lengthy.